# PDFBox - Getting Content height

Tags: pdfbox

How can i get the content height of a given page with pdfbox? I have X pages, where i need to add Y elements to. Once the first page is full, it should start a new page, putting out the rest of the Y elements and of course starting another page, once the second is also full.

So: How do i determine if the page is full - aka the content height?

I have something like this:

```
private static void addChapters() throws IOException {
    for(int i = 0; i < chapters.size(); i++) {

        // if page is full, add a new page and start printing on the new page here

        // Chapter Headline
        // some output here...

        // Data table
        // some more output here

        contentStream.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *I have X pages, where i need to add Y elements to. Once the first page is full, it should start a new page* - PDFBox only implements a lowlevel API for PDF generation. This means that you have to provide the layouting code yourself. Usually this layouting code *keeps track of where on the page it currently inserts content*,and, therefore, *knows when the page is full and starts a new one*. Your code sceleton unfortunately misses these parts (*some output here*, *some more output here*). Thus, we can hardly tell you how that code can recognize that the page is full.

Answer (score 1):

PdfBox doesn´t have the tools to control page layout. What I´ve done at first was to multiply the number of results I wanted in a single page and their size to obtain the total height I was about to use. Then you can start writting in an Y higher than this result and change to a new page when the fixed number is reached.

However, at the end I was trying to print results like in a table, so I used Boxable for Pdfbox(https://github.com/dhorions/boxable) which handles page switching for you.

Comment: could you show me how boxable handles page switching?